# how to process hidden values in create method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, hidden-field

I have this method for proccess "create" form in asp.net:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "question_id, feedback_id")] feedback_questions feedback_questions)
```

In form `question_id` I get from select box, but `feedback_id` I want to get by hidden value.

My form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>feedback_questions</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.question_id, "choose question: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("question_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.feedback_id, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                // here I want hidden attribute for feedback_id, which will have value @ViewBag.feedback_id
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: why are you using viewbag if the property is on your model?

Comment: Just set the value of `feedback_id` in the controller before you pass the model to the view (not in `ViewBag`) and use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.feedback_id)` in the view. Note its also pointless to ad a label for a hidden input, as is generating a `ValidationMessageFor()` (hidden inputs are not validated by default)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `feedback_id` is being passed to the view from another view or layout, but since it's on your model, why not just pass it in to the Create view on the Get action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new feedback_questions() { feedback_id = ?? });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "question_id, feedback_id")] feedback_questions feedback_questions)
{ 
    return View(feedback_questions);      
}
```

then you can just use the HiddenFor helper

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.feedback_id)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>feedback_questions</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.question_id, "choose question: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("question_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.Hidden("feedback_id", @ViewBag.feedback_id)` where `feedback_id` is the name of the hidden input,  that should match the name of the property you are binding to.